# POM gears and metal fittings

Tags: motor, mechanism, gearing

I'm looking at [this setup](https://img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i1/650686955/TB2i_qfbpXXXXXPXpXXXXXXXXXX-650686955.jpg):

[image]

where the POM bevel gears are fitted with some kind of metal (bronze?) tube inside which fits over the shaft. What benefits does this method provide? Is it to allow the shaft to free-spin? The metal fitting wouldn't be able to grip on the shaft - right?

Is it supposed to be a canonical approach to fitting a POM gear for (relatively) high-load applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to turn a gear on a shaft without turning the shaft unless it is mechanically linked to another gear. The reason for the brass sleeve is probably for the set screw to have a stronger material than plastic to anchor in.

Comment: Does the brass sleeve grip on the shaft though? It's metal and it won't stretch much (if at all) - right? Is fitting a metal sleeve over a recommended approach?

Comment: @John Munroe, no, it almost certainly has a set screw hole on the other side, It could be press fit or maybe brazed on too, but brazing is unlikely with plastic.